# Fetching menu items and its sub-items to accordion using react, axios and mysql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, axios, accordion

iam trying to fetch menu items and its sub items from mysql database to an accordion using react and axios. i could fetch the main items but failed to fetch each menu sub items.

menu item table(id, menuitem)
menu sub item table(id, menuitemid, menusubitem).
would you please help.
Thanks in advance.

here is my code

```
// fetch menu items
import axios from 'axios';

const FetchDashboard = async () => {
  const sendData = {
    groupId: localStorage.getItem('groupId')
  }

  const result = await axios.post('http://localhost/sits_api/login/dashboard.php', sendData);
    // return the result
    return result;
  }
 
export default FetchDashboard;
```

```
// fetch sub menu items
import axios from 'axios';

const FetchDashboardSubList = async () => {
  const sendData = {
    groupId: localStorage.getItem('groupId'),
    moduleId: 1 // this parameter for each menu
  }

  const result = await axios.post('http://localhost/sits_api/login/dashboardSubList.php', sendData);
    // return the result
    return result;
  }
 
export default FetchDashboardSubList;
```

then i import fetch dashboard and fetchdashboard subitems to my dashboard.js and rendering accordion like that

```
// dashboard.js 
// some code

<div className="accordion">
                {data.map(({ title, content }) => (
                <AccordionMenu title={title} content=
                  {FetchDashboardSubList().then(resp => {
                    setDataSubList(resp.data);
                    dataSubList.map(({itemNameEng,pageLink}) => (
                    <AccordionMenuSubList itemNameEng={itemNameEng} pageLink={pageLink}/>                   
                    ))
                  })} 
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
```

this would return the menu items but no sub items.

// menu item table structure(id, name)
values (1, system admin)
values (2, data setup)
values (3, outpatient section)
......

// menu sub item table structure(id, name, menu item id)
values(1, comapny data, 1)
values(2, user groups, 1)
values(3, user list, 1)

values(4, medicine list, 2)
values(5, patient list, 2)
values(6, procedure list, 2)

values(7, new visit, 3)
values(8, edit visit, 3)
values(9, visit report, 3)

Comment: For clarity, are you able to access the sub-items on the menu without being able to render them in the accordion, or you haven't been able to achieve any?

Answer (score 0):

State Update is Asynchronous in React. Maybe the Datasublist is not updated while you mapping through it for sub items. You can map the resp.data instead..

```
         <div className="accordion">
                {data.map(({ title, content }) => (
                <AccordionMenu title={title} content=
                  {FetchDashboardSubList().then(resp => {
                    setDataSubList(resp.data);
                    //  resp.data instead of dataSublist
                    resp.data.map(({itemNameEng,pageLink}) => (
                    <AccordionMenuSubList itemNameEng={itemNameEng} pageLink= 
                      {pageLink}/>                   
                    ))
                  })} 
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
```

Comment: sorry, not working

Comment: i guess i should pass the menu item id parameter to the function fetching the sub menu items. but i do not know how?

Comment: i got this error in console "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Could you share the values of result comes from the FetchDashboardSubList function ?

Comment: i edited the post to show the table structure and data coming from them.